# Issues in running deviceQuery of Cuda SDK

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I compiled the sdk examples yesterday and I ran few of them also. But today I am trying to run the deviceQuery and in the ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/bin/linux/release folder by issuing ./deviceQuery command and it is showing:

```
 ./deviceQuery: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Can you check your CUDA install path and make sure there symbolic links in the lib directory that link from libcudart.so to libcudart.so.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the path environment for CUDA

```
goto /etc/

$ gksudo gedit environment
```

There you can see PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

something like that,,, just append the following

```
:/usr/local/cuda/bin"
```

save and exit the editor

reload the path

```
 source environment
```

now set LD_LIBRARY_PATH: (be in /etc/ directory itself)

```
 $ gksudo gedit ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf
```

(which creates a new file)
paste following into the file

```
  /usr/local/cuda/lib64
  /usr/local/cuda/lib
```

save and quit the editor
reload LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Now run the samples.

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply. All that you have mentioned was already been done before but the error is still coming. However when I write the following lines in the terminal I can run the compiled examples. The lines are as followes

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib:/opt/cuda/lib64
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib:/opt/cuda/lib64' >> ~/.bash_profile
I was very busy for last few days and comiling my project issuing these commands so I got late in replying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the environment variables?
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Please refer to CUDA_Getting_Started_Guide_For_Linux for detail.