# Why is CUDA flummoxed by variable declaration in bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, cuda

I recently installed CUDA 5.0 on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 system by following instructions on the [NVidia](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) site, [this](http://www.zamaudio.com/?p=651) site, and [this](http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/) site.  (As a note, Ubuntu 12.04 is not one of the OS's listed as supported for CUDA 5.0 on the NVidia site, but clearly others had installed it and gotten it running on their systems.)  After installing the drivers and packages correctly, I would try to compile and run

1) the first program in the included samples (the executable deviceQuery in ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/), and

2) the first GPU-capable program -- simple_kernel.cu in Chapter 03 -- included in the source code (available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0)) for the *CUDA By Example* book published by NVidia.

Executable 1) I obtained by running `make` in the corresponding directory; executable 2) I obtained with `nvcc simple_kernel.cu`.  The result for both was this output:

```
./deviceQuery: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

For clarity, yes I had set my `PATH` variable to include `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin`, as well as my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to include both `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib` and `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64`, and yes there were links `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib/libcudart.so` pointing to `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib/libcudart.so.5.0` as well as `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib/libcudart.so` pointing to `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib/libcudart.so.5.0`.  But this is leading to my question...

I had modified my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables by adding lines in my ~/.bashrc file

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin` 
and 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64`

Opening a terminal window and typing `echo $PATH` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would show that both variables had been set correctly, yet I was having the problem running CUDA executables described above.

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416629/issues-in-running-devicequery-of-cuda-sdk) posting on stackoverflow and tried the suggestion offered by sivapal ayyappan nadar -- setting `PATH` by modifying `/etc/environment` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by modifying `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda50.conf` (I simultaneously commented out the corresponding lines in ~/.bashrc).  Now when I compile and run my CUDA samples, they work!

So, now my question: what is going on here?  Why is the libcudart library being properly linked when LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda50.conf` but not when it is set in `~/.bashrc`?  What does the one do that the other does not?  Or, is this not the real source of my problem?

When replying, please bear in mind my motives for asking the question.  I want to 1) understand the intricacies of the Linux system, and 2) post a possible solution for others who might be encountering the same problem even after following the other excellent instructions that are available.  Many thanks.

Comment: Nice, I just learned the word 'flummox' :) No idea, what your question is about though, sorry.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for correcting my spelling.  I've changed the post title accordingly.

Comment: So, the TLDR version is you can't run CUDA applications (on a non-supported platform) because the runtime library can't be fuond?

Comment: @talonmies: No, the TLDR version is "I can run CUDA applications, but only when LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda50.conf instead of .bashrc (or so it seems to me).  Why is this?"

Comment: When you say you opened a terminal window to `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, does that mean that this terminal was separate from whatever you tried to run this code in? Did you try running and verifying in the same terminal? (.bashrc isn't source by everything)

Comment: @thatotherguy: yes, I would run nvcc and the resulting executables in the same terminal window/session as the echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH command.

Comment: I think I am right in concluding that this really isn't anything more than peripherally related to CUDA. Basically you have edited some environment settings into a .bashrc file and the linux link loader isn't picking them up, and you want to know why. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: @talonmies. Your summary sounds reasonable. I hadn't encountered this problem until working with cuda, so made the association automatically. It could be nothing more than a general Linux question, though. So, my questions would be 1) why isn't the Linux loader picking up on environment variables set in .bashrc, and 2) why is setting those variables in .bashrc working for others who have installed the same package, on the same system, and not for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of an interesting topic that I'll try and explain. So, in this example I install a small library, [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) to test. I'll go ahead and configure it to install in a non-standard directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/ubuntu/mystuff
```

Now after doing a `make install` this warning comes up:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
```

Okay so I'll go ahead and try and link against it using one of the test suite programs:

```
$ gcc test_dump.c -ljansson 
test_dump.c:8:21: fatal error: jansson.h: No such file or directory
```

In order for C to know about what it can use, it first needs to know about include files. Luckily this only needs to happen at compile time. We pass in the include directory using `-I` so `gcc` knows where to find the include file:

```
$ gcc test_dump.c -I/home/ubuntu/mystuff/include -ljansson
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljansson
```

Okay now back to the linking issue. So let's try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` while linking:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib" gcc test_dump.c -I/home/ubuntu/mystuff/include -ljansson
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljansson
```

That doesn't work, and the reason behind this is that gcc is looking in different directories, as can be shown by running:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

To tell gcc to work with the directory we want, `-L` is used:

```
$ gcc test_dump.c -I/home/ubuntu/mystuff/include -L/home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib -ljansson
$
```

Now we can use a program called `ldd` to see what it links against:

```
$ ldd a.out 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fc4c872d000)
        libjansson.so.4 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc4c8366000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc4c872e000)
```

You'll notice that it says "not found" for the library we want. Now to try and take care of that problem:

```
$ LD_RUN_PATH="/home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib" gcc test_dump.c -I/home/ubuntu/mystuff/include -L/home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib -ljansson
```

This is one way, using `LD_RUN_PATH`. Instead of linking to just a library, it links to the full path to the library. Running `ldd` again shows this:

```
$ ldd a.out 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff481d7000)
        libjansson.so.4 => /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib/libjansson.so.4 (0x00007fe86b0dd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe86ad18000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe86b2eb000)
```

Now when we go to try this without `LD_RUN_PATH` involved we get this:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libjansson.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To solve this, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib" ./a.out
$
```

However, this is a bit of a hack and frowned upon. David Barr has a [great writeup on that matter](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html). What's happening is that there's a dynamic library loader, `ld.so/ld-linux.so` that "loads the shared libraries needed by a program, prepares the program to run, and then runs it". If you look at the `ld.so` manpage it states:

```
   The necessary shared libraries needed by the program are searched for in the following order

   o      Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (LD_AOUT_LIBRARY_PATH for a.out programs).  Except if the executable is a setuid/setgid binary, in which case it is ignored.

   o      From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache which contains a compiled list of candidate libraries previously found in the augmented library path. Libraries installed in hardware capabilities
          directories (see below) are prefered to other libraries.

   o      In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib.
```

That `/etc/ld.so.cache` is where you want that path to be in. This cache is generated by `ldconfig` using `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If you look at that file on Ubuntu:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Is all that it says. In the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory, by default, is directories for glib, gcc, and `/usr/local/lib` since it's outside the default path. To add the directory we want to the cache, you simply add a file in that directory:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/50-jansson.conf
- add /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib to the file -
$ sudo ldconfig
```

This will regenerate that `/etc/ld.so.cache` file for the loader. You can confirm the directory was picked up by having `ldconfig` print out the cached directories:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep "mystuff"
        libjansson.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib/libjansson.so.4
        libjansson.so (libc6,x86-64) => /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib/libjansson.so
```

Now if we try doing the `ldd` run again:

```
$ ldd a.out 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1e510000)
        libjansson.so.4 => /home/ubuntu/mystuff/lib/libjansson.so.4 (0x00007f529da67000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f529d6a8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f529dc7b000)
```

And finally run the program:

```
$ ./a.out
$
```

It all works! That's a look into what's happening on the backend for when you're doing linking. For more detailed information, I'd recommend looking at `man ld.so` and `man ldconfig`. Feel free to ask away if you need any clarification.

Comment: This is an awesome response - I'll go ahead and accept it. Still, the crux of my doubt remains, and is even greater after your explanation! As you pointed out, the ld.so manpage says ld will first look for shared libraries using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, then use the cache in /etc/ld.so.conf.d. In my first attempt to get CUDA to run, I set this variable in .bashrc, which seems to me to be equivalent to your "bit of a hack" solution above. It was only when I set the variable in /etc/ld.so.conf.d - the second choice for ld - did things work correctly. What's up with that?

Comment: @wayeast I noticed that and was looking into a bit. When you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`, what happens when you run `ldd` on the `a.out`/`deviceQuery` binary? That should help a little with debugging. Feel free to use gist.github.com if the output is a bit long for comments.

Comment: I'm not eager to try to revert to the old circumstances on the machine in question because it's a shared machine.  I'll see if I can't replicate the situation on a different one to be able to answer your question, but it might take me a little while to get to the resources and to the task.  Just so you know I'm not ignoring you in the meantime... Thanks for keeping up with it.